# ayuda con expresión regular

Tags: java

quiero que la expresión regular acepte empezando la cadena solo números del 1 al 9 y positivos, sin espacios en blancos tengo este método con la expresión

`public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        return (str.matches("^[[1-9]|+]?\\d*(\\.\\d+)?") && str.equals("") == false);
    }`

le agregue el `[1-9]` pero nada, no se mucho de expresiones regulares,encontré esta expresión que valida solo números y le agregue lo del espacio y la parte del + empezando la cadena  para que solo me acepte positivos pero no se como agregarle lo del que solo me acepte al principio números del 1 al 9

Comment: Hola tu mensaje es un poco confuso,  podrias mostrar un ejemplo de lo que que quieres?

Comment: @ReneGarnica me acepte dígitos positivos del 1 al 9, pero si pongo 0 me lo rechace

Comment: pero solo quires validar numeros ejemplo "2345" nada de letras u otro tipo de caracters?

Comment: @ReneGarnica exacto puros números positivos nada de otros caracteres

Comment: @ReneGarnica osea esta bien pero aun así no me acepta el 200, el 0 al principio también quiero que lo valide el 022 no, pero el 220 si me entiendes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola en base a los comentarios puedes probar esta solucion

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   String numeros="123456789";

   if(esNumero(numeros))
        System.out.println("Es un numero");
   else
        System.out.println("No es un numero");


}

public static boolean esNumero(String numero){
    return numero.matches("^[1-9][0-9]*$");
}
```

Comment: osea no quiero que acepte esto 022 pero si 220 me entiendes? el 0 al principio de la cadena no

Comment: Ahi lo tienes corregido espero sea lo que buscas saludos...

Comment: gracias si me sirvió